# Why is my python code for finding the intersection between lists not working as intended?

Tags: python

First, sorry if this question is too basic, I am still a beginner in programming. I was trying to create a code to generate two random lists and find their intersection, without duplicates, but my idea is not working as intended, which is using this setup with list comprehensions:

```
import random
a = random.choices(range(0, 10), k = 7) 
b = random.choices(range(0, 10), k = 7) 
print(a) 
print(b) 
c = []
c = [i for i in a if i in b if i not in c]
```

Here are some of the results:

```
a = [1, 4, 1, 7, 2, 3, 8] b = [5, 6, 4, 9, 4, 4, 1] c = [1, 4, 1]

a = [7, 3, 8, 4, 7, 5, 3] b = [3, 3, 7, 8, 1, 4, 7] c = [7, 3, 8, 4, 7, 3]
```

Clearly, there are duplicates being included. Why is it happening? Shouldn't list c be updated after each loop and the code check if the duplicate is already there and hence not include it?

Comment: If you use `set()` this is a standard way to create an iteratable without duplicates...outside of that you'll need to manually check. And a common use-case is `unique_list = list(set([1,1,2,3,3]))` where you end with `[1,2,3]`

Comment: And, if you create sets out of the lists as suggested by @ViaTech, if you want to then see the intersection of two sets, you can use the [`&` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection).

Comment: @safay to be clear, that only works on sets and set-like objects, not lists. You can create sets out of them, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Shouldn't list c be updated after each loop and the code check if the duplicate is already there and hence not include it?

No.

In an assignment like `c = [1, 2, 3]`, the expression on the right hand side of the `=` is evaluated first (in its entirety), and *then* the name on the left hand side of the `=` is bound to that value.

The fact that you had to do `c = []` to prevent an exception from being raised in the body of your list comprehension is a clue -- if you didn't have that, `c` wouldn't be bound to *anything* until the list comprehension completed.  With your code as you have it, `c` is bound to an empty list, and then it gets rebound to the completed list comprehension.  There is no in-between state where `c` is bound to the list comprehension while it's still in progress.

If you were to write this as a `for` loop:

```
c = []
for i in a:
    if i in b:
        if i not in c:
            c.append(i)
```

you get the behavior you want, because now `c` is actually being modified (via the `c.append` call) on each iteration of the loop.

It is simpler to avoid duplicates by using a set instead of a list; this is often as straightforward as using a set comprehension instead of a list comprehension:

```
c = {i for i in a if i in b}
```

but since you're trying to find an intersection, it's simpler yet if you make sets out of `a` and `b` and then use the set intersection operator:

```
c = set(a) & set(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you place your comprehension in a call to `c.extend`, the additions will be processed as you go and your code will work as expected:

```
c = [] 
c.extend(i for i in a if i in b if i not in c)
```

Comment: This is neat, and works as a great illustration of the difference between a generator and a comprehension.